# distributed transactions involving web services

Tags: service, web, distributed-transactions

What are the general ways of doing distributed transactions with web services ? Lets assume I have an application / service that talks to two other web services within some sort of global transaction . I am not very sure how the two phase commits work in this scenario .

Answer (score 3):

This is not a direct answer to your question but a pointer to some good background material. I happened to be researching this topic recently and stumbled across this paper that both gives a decent review of the state of the art (circa 2004) and transaction alternatives such as tentative holding.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221152644_Web_Service_Composition_Transaction_Management

This student thesis also covers a lot of the same ground:

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.151.3803&rep=rep1&type=pdf

As does this W3C document:

https://www.w3.org/TR/tenthold-1/

In general, it appears these approaches to transactions over web services haven't gained much traction.